# How to get the months in plotly express in line chart in order

Tags: python, plotly

How to get the months in order in line chart in plotly express. here is the data set
and code

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
fig = go.FigureWidget()

df_long=pd.melt(final_line_data, id_vars=['Month'], value_vars=['Amount_2016', 'Amount_2017', 'Amount_2018', 'Amount_2019'])
fig = px.line(df_long, x='Month', y='value', color='variable')

fig.show()

Month   Amount_2016 Year_2016   Amount_2017 Year_2017   Amount_2018 Year_2018   Amount_2019 Year_2019
0   Apr 1395463.0   2016.0  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   Aug 2016836.0   2016.0  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   Dec 2300493.0   2016.0  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   Jul 2098968.0   2016.0  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
4   Jun 1748118.0   2016.0  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

We can add the argument category_orders={"Month": ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]} to your px.line() call.